# Use two themes in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use one theme for Admin Panel and one theme is a separate which I want to show my visitors. I mean to say that there should be separate themes for visitor and Administrator of a website.
How to do in asp.net mvc?
Because in mvc we have only one file _Layout.cshtml and here we have to attach only one theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define second layout in shared folder with another name like _AdminLayout etc. call the @RenderBody() function in it,
Now you can Render layouts via different ways,

**1. Define layout in View:**

```
    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "View_Title";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
     }
```

**2.  Rendering layout page from ActionResult (using Controller. View extension method):**

```
    public ActionResult Action_Result_Name()
    {
        return View("Action_Result_Name","_AdminLayout");
    }
```

**3. Using _ViewStart.cshtml Page:**

_ViewStart.cshtml page used to define the default layout page for the MVC application.

```
@{   
    layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
```

If you are using Identity framework then you can define layouts on the basis of conditions as well

```
@{
   if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
   {
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
   }
   else
   {
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create as many layout files as needed. So in your case, it is a good idea to create an admin area which has it's own layout page in which you can use your admin theme css files

[Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas) are logical grouping of related functionality and files needed for that (controllers,views, styles,code etc).Areas provide a way to partition a large  Web app into smaller functional groupings.

For your normal visitors, their pages/views uses the default layout and for the admin users, they get the views rendered from the admin area where it has it's own layout.

For the views from admin area (or even the `_Viewstart.cshtml`), you can explicitly specify the admin layout

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: No brother it's not good. We should have a two _Layout.cshtml files where two themes are linking.
If I create too much files for visitor themes then there are chances to slow response of my website.

Comment: @Shyju's answer is the optimal approach. What problem do you have exactly with doing it this way? Your comment is not clear.

Comment: Yess Cris Pratt you saying right, answer is not cleare